# Calculate file sizes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have document file sizes as follows in a table:

```
Filesize
7013    
14050
1300050
7775
```

The file sizes are in bytes by default.
I want to use sql to cast the file sizes into KBs, MBs or GBs accordingly.

Have been able to use the following sql to calculate the file size,
but i dont know how to group them into KBs, MBs, GBs.

```
SELECT
    CAST(
        ROUND(
            SUM( CAST(filesize AS Numeric(15,4)) / 1024 )
           ,2
        ) AS decimal(10,2)
    ) 
FROM Attachments
```

My ultimate goal is to have:

```
 6.848 KBs     
 13.720 KBs
 1.240 MBs
 7.593 KBs
```

I am using the conversion rate of 1KiloByte = 1024 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
DECLARE @X NUMERIC(18,4) = 23;
SELECT CASE
WHEN @X <= 1024                             THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @X) + ' BYTES'
WHEN @X >1024 AND @X <= 1048576             THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @X/1024) + ' KB'
WHEN @X >1048576 AND @X <= 1073741824       THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @X/1048576) + ' MB'
WHEN @X >1073741824 AND @X <= 1099511627776 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @X/1073741824) + ' GB'
ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @X/1099511627776) + ' TB'
END
```

To use your table and field for example

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN yt.FileSize <= 1024                                     THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, yt.FileSize) + ' BYTES'
WHEN yt.FileSize >1024 AND yt.FileSize <= 1048576            THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, yt.FileSize/1024) + ' KB'
WHEN yt.FileSize >1048576 AND yt.FileSize <= 1073741824      THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, yt.FileSize/1048576) + ' MB'
WHEN yt.FileSize >1073741824 AND yt.FileSize <= 109951162777 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR, yt.FileSize/1073741824) + ' GB'
ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, yt.FileSize/1099511627776) + ' TB'
END
FROM YourTable yt
```

Comment: You could even use a function to call and output the desired output

Comment: Nice one, but how do i integrate the table name and the table columns into the query?

Comment: In this select query, replace @X with the name of the field. i shall edit my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I just need to work on the upper and lower limits now.

Comment: Sure. Hope you get what you need

Comment: The calculations for a Gigabyte and a Terabyte are off... I've updated the code accordingly...